# LoadTesting, How to get work done in TestInitialize without effecting Avg. Test Time

Tags: c#, unit-testing, load-testing

Some of the tests in my loadtest have two steps involved in order get the data I need, however I want to test the time it take for each component of that process individually so I can easily save it to my load test database, and allow another person to create a report on it. For example I need to test the times of these two methods:

```
public FooObject[] GetFooList()  
public FooObject GetFoo( FooId )
```

The way you would use these is like so:

```
 FooObject[] results = GetFooList();  
 FooObject finalResult = GetFoo( results[0].FooId );
```

I want to know how long GetFooList() and GetFoo() takes to complete, so I thought by doing the prep work for needed for GetFoo() in the TestInitialize method, that it wouldn't effect the test time that was recorded. After some testing with thread.sleep(), I realized that its not the case. Here is my class as it stands now.

```
[TestClass]  
public class MyTestClass
{  

  public static object f;  
  public static Random r = new Random();  

  public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }  

  [TestInitialize]  
  public void testInit() {  
    if( TestContext.TestName == "GetFooTest" ) {  
        FooObject[] results = GetFooList();  
        f = results[ r.nextInt( results.Length ) ];  
    }  
  }  

  [TestMethod]  
  public void GetFooTest()  
  {   
    GetFoo( ((FooObject)f).FooId );  
  }  

  [TestMethod]
  public void GetFooListTest()
  {
     GetFooList();
  }  
}
```

I was wondering if:
1. There was a way for the load test to ignore the TestInitalize component of a test, or
2. if not if there was a suggestion on how I could get around this issue.

I have about 10 or so different pairs of these methods to do ( GetBarList, GetBar, etc...) that's why I store **f** in a generic object, and eventually let the test initialize have a big switch statement. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

IFAIK, the timings not including the TestInitialize.
Also, you can use with Timer:

```
this.TestContext.BeginTimer("transaction name");  
//the code you want to measure   
this.TestContext.EndTimer("transaction name");
```